# Isometric embedding of 1-manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Suppose the unit circle $\gamma$ in $R^2$ is not endowed with the canonical 
inner product of $R^2$.  Let the riemannian metric defined be
$g:=[2, 1;1, 1]$.  So the length is measured with this metric on the
circle.
Q.1 Is there a way to construct the isometric embedding
of this  $(\gamma,g)$ in some $(R^n,can)$?
Q.2 In general given any such $g$ can we always construct 
an isometric embedding?

Comment: Your $g$ is not a Riemannian metric as it is not symmetric.


Comment: g is symmetric positive definite.  Question is to find such an embedding constructively.  I agree Nash's embedding theorem is the answer for sure about the existence.  But how do I construct it?

Comment: Your metric has constant coefficients, hence there is a linear map that transforms it into the standard Euclidean metric. Restrict this map to the circle and you are done. For the specific example $g=[2,1;1,1]$, the linear map $(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,y)$ does the job.

Comment: As for Q2, every Riemannian metric on the circle is isometric to a Euclidean circle of a suitable radius and hence admits an isometric embedding to $\mathbb R^2$. The said isometry can be written explicitly in terms of an arc-length parameterization.

Comment: I think you mean it should be $(x,y)\to (x,x+y)$.  It works!  I am not sure about the answer of second question.  I'll try to work out an example as you suggested using arc-length parametrization.
 

Comment: I suggest you provide some background or motivation. Right now the question looks like it is from someone stuck at the first paragraph of a textbook. (And if this indeed is the case, there is nothing wrong with it, but math.stackexchange.com is a better place for the question.)

Comment: And yes, I meant $(x+y,x)$.

Comment: Motivation: I work on curve reconstruction in $SE(3)$. And the focus is on the simple closed curves in $SE(3)$. The exp map for $SE(3)$ is known and the riemannian metric defined on $se(3)$ is $g:=[\alpha I_3 0,0,\beta I_3]$. Given a curve in it, I want to find an isometric embeddig of this curve in some $R^n$. Furthermore, I want to construct an isometric embedding of $SE(3)$ to some $R^n$?. – Pratik 0 secs ago

Comment: 1) Why is it useful or interesting to isometrically embed a curve contained in $SE(3)$ into $R^n$? As far as I can tell, no new information is gained by such an embedding at all. 2) The same goes for an isometric embedding of $SE(3)$ into $R^n$. A long time ago, when abstract manifolds were first invented, people were more comfortable studying them if they were viewed as submanifolds of $R^n$. However, by now we know enough to know that in fact this approach adds only more noise and no useful geometric information.

Comment: Question asked by a student was, if we could reconstruct curve in $R^n$ can't we claim we can reconstruct curves in riemannian manifolds?  Refering to the [Nash 1956] embedding theorem.
I accept the fact that we know enough to deal with this intrinsically. I wanted to make a point to students that it is difficult to come up with such isometric embeddings and at the end it does not convey any useful information as you correctly pointed out. I am trying to make few examples of manifolds used in engineering applications.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "reconstruct curve" means?

Comment: Let $C:[0,1]\to M$ be a smooth and simple closed curve. And $S \subset C$ is a finite sample of $C$. Can we reconstruct $C$ given $S$? The problem thus involves first suggesting a sampling criterion, or characterization of $S$. Next step is to provide an algorithm which provablaly re-orders the point set in $S$. Finally it involves suggesting an interpolation scheme to get near to the smooth curve $C$. The interesting part of the problem is suggesting the characterization of $S$ and the re-ordering algorithm.
Ref- http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3359

Answer (score 0):

Whilst what you have given is not a Riemannian metric, the general question has a famous answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_Embedding_Theorem

Comment: $g$ is symmetric, now is there a tractable construction possible for such an embedding?  If yes how to proceed about constructing one in the case stated here.

Comment: @Pratik: in the case of a circle, yes: as Sergei suggested in the commented above, you can construct the embedding by parametrizing the circle with arc-length.